# Highlight variable and function names in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have to analyze a lot of Delphi code in XE4.
For that I'm missing a feature to highlight a variable or function/procedure name by just clicking on it (like Eclipse or Netbeans does).

Is there an option for this I haven't found so far or can this be fixed with an addon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to try [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en). It greatly enhances IDE and also adds this feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the built-in Find function. When you do, it highlights all of the matches in the entire file. Best of all, no add-on is required!

Comment: If it's search feature still controlled from that bottom bar in Delphi XE4, then it's not the best (for me) :-) With CnPack I can just press F3 to search highlighted text, which, as you correctly say, highlights matchings.

Comment: F3 has worked for searching in Delphi since day 1. Maybe your keyboard mapping isn't correct.

Comment: Are you sure ? I think you must first perform a search and then by F3 find a next match.

Comment: Yes, F3 finds the next match. <ctrl>-F lets you enter the search text.

Comment: Yes, but with CnPack you can just select text and press F3 and it performs the initial search (and subsequent F3 goes to the next matching). You don't need to press CTRL + F and Enter.

Comment: That's fine, but it's not what you asked about in your question.

Comment: I know. That's why I gave you my upvote. I just wanted to point out that with CnPack it's a bit easier, and that I hate that built-in bottom search bar :-)

Comment: Incremental search (Ctrl+E) does the highlighting, too.

Comment: In the keyboard bindings I use, "Classic", `F3` opens a file, so CnPack would be a hindrance.